# find record between min(date) and min(date)+value sql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select a record between 2 tables

base on the condition:

- highest price
- date range between min(date) and min(date)+20 years

```
Select PRICE, NAME, ORDER_DATE 
 from customers a, orders b 
 where a.ORDER_ID = b.ID and 
b.PRICE =  (SELECT MAX(PRICE) FROM orders) and 
b.ORDER_DATE between '1900-01-01' and '2000-01-01'
```

I am not sure whats the correct way to set the date range between

min(ORDER_DATE) and min(ORDER_DATE)+20Years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a proper join on the tables, sort by price descending and get the top row:

```
SELECT b.PRICE, a.NAME, b.ORDER_DATE 
FROM customers a INNER JOIN orders b 
ON a.ORDER_ID = b.ID 
WHERE b.ORDER_DATE <= (SELECT MIN(ORDER_DATE) FROM orders) + INTERVAL 20 YEAR
ORDER BY b.PRICE DESC LIMIT 1
```

This query will not return ties.
If you want ties:

```
SELECT b.PRICE, a.NAME, b.ORDER_DATE 
FROM customers a INNER JOIN orders b 
ON a.ORDER_ID = b.ID 
WHERE b.ORDER_DATE <= (SELECT MIN(ORDER_DATE) FROM orders) + INTERVAL 20 YEAR
  AND b.PRICE = (SELECT MAX(PRICE) FROM orders WHERE ORDER_DATE <= (SELECT MIN(ORDER_DATE) FROM orders) + INTERVAL 20 YEAR)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Should I always use join table when searching across tables?

Comment: The code that you use: `from customers a, orders b where...` is an old-style inner join. You should use the (not so) new syntax with `INNER JOIN...`. The result is the same but the new syntax is more flexible.

Comment: I see, Thanks for the tips